# Understanding the Minimum Principle in Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, maxima-minima, online-resources, maximum-principle

The minimum principle in complex analysis, in my textbook, is stated like this:

> Let $f: U\to \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant analytical function, $f(z)\ne 0$, and U a conex of $\mathbb{C}$. Then the function: $g: U\to \mathbb{R}^+$, $g(z)=|f(z)|$ has no local minimums.

I've seen other variations of the principle, with varying degrees of formalism, and from what I gather, the idea is that if a function $f$ is analytical and has no zeros, then the minimum values of $|f(z)|$ must either be on the boundary of its domain or not exist.
So in case the domain is an open set, since there is no boundary, the function can't have any mininums that aren't zeros at all.

The reason for this is that if the module of the function had a local minimum, then we would be able to define a disk/other compact set where the function was constant, and so, by the identity theorem, it would all be constant.

Is this analysis correct? I'm finding it hard to apply this in exercises, because it's a very strange idea to wrap ones mind around. Particularly the last explanation, with the identity theorem.

P.S.: If anyone knows of any online resources (video lectures, books, etc.) that offer more visual representation of complex analysis, that would be very helpful!

Comment: Yep, you have this right. All minima must lie on the boundary (and there can be multiple minima over a closed $U$... see the [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle) on this for example) by the exact reasoning you give

Comment: Geometrically, you might think of it as analytic functions needing to be "wavy", in that they perterbate between the highest-high and the lowest-low on the boundary. If your set is open, then we know the minimum on the closure is on the boundary, so given any "candidate" local minimum inside but *close to* the boundary, we could (by continuity) always find a point closer to the boundary with smaller magnitude

Comment: If $f$ is analytic at $a$ and $a$ is a local extremum of $|f|$ then $f$ is constant, this is immediate from $f(a+z)= f(a)+Cz^n+O(z^{n+1})$. When we only assume that $f$ is holomorphic then use the Cauchy integral formula proving that $f$ is analytic.

Comment: $1/f$ is analytic when $f$ has no zeroes and the maximum modulus applied to it, gives the minimum modulus applied to $f$