# Cauchy's minimum principle

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

At the moment I'm trying to understand a proof of the fundamental theorem of algebra. The author uses several facts known from analysis lectures. Under these facts is one I didn't know in the formulation. He states that every real and continuous function $f$ that is defined on a compact set $S$ has its minimum there.

Now my questions:

1. I suppose this does also hold for functions  $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. Is that right? Since he uses this for complex polynomial functions later on.
2. Do you recognize the fact in this statement I found here ([Understanding the Minimum Principle in Complex Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739317/understanding-the-minimum-principle-in-complex-analysis))?

Comment: When you say this is used for functions $f : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{C}$, I think you mean that the absolute value attains its minimum on $S$, so that is about $|f| : \Bbb{C} \to \Bbb{R}$. This is a general fact about continuous functions on compact subsets of metric spaces; I think the the minimum principle discussed in your linked page is a more specialised result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In general, if you have a continuous function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $K$ a compact subset of a *topological space* $X$, then both $\min\{f(x):x\in K\}$ and $\max\{f(x):x\in K\}$ exist.

The linked question is more about the properties of analytic functions, in particular, the [maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, now my problem is solved.