# If $\vert z+1 \vert \gt 2$ then $\vert z^3+1 \vert \gt 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\vert z+1 \vert \gt 2$. Prove that $\vert z^3+1 \vert \gt 1$.

I spent a lot of time trying to solve that. I tried the triangle inequality in the form $\vert z-w \vert \geq \vert \vert z \vert -\vert w \vert \vert$, in the standard form and also to use the trigonometric form of $z$ satisfying the first inequality together with the equality $z\bar{z}=\vert z \vert^2$ and some trigonometric manipulations. However, each approach doesn't lead me to the proof.

I will be very grateful for any hint which could get me closer to a solution. The complex analysis is not allowed.

Comment: The sum of two cubes $z^3+1$ factors as $(z+1)(z^2-z+1)$. So, is $|z^2-z+1| > \frac{1}{2}$ provably true? If so, then $|z^3+1| = |z+1||z^2-z+1| > (2)(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739317/understanding-the-minimum-principle-in-complex-analysis) will help and tell you that the extremum of $|z^3+1|$ lies precisely on the boundary of the domain i.e. on $|z+1| = 2$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang I tried also to prove your inequality by factoring $z^2-z+1$ as $(z-\epsilon)(z-\bar{\epsilon})$ where $\epsilon$ is a one of $3$-rd roots of -1 different from -1 and to think about distances of $z$ from $\epsilon$ and $\bar{\epsilon}$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer The problem is the fact that it is an exercise for first year of undergraduate course from linear algebra at the Mathematics department. I am a tutor and I had given this exercise, but I realized that I am not sure how to figure out without using complex analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $z=r(\cos \theta+i\sin\theta)$ (so $z^3=r^3(\cos 3\theta+i\sin 3\theta)),$ the original problem is equivalent to the statement $$r^2+2r\cos\theta>3\Rightarrow r^3+2\cos 3\theta>0. ~~(1)$$

Letting $x=\cos\theta,$ condition $(1)$ can be written as $$r^2+2xr-3>0\Rightarrow r^3+2(4x^3-3x)>0,~~(2)$$ where one uses the identity $\cos 3\theta=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta.$

Note that $$r^2+2xr-3>0$$
$$\Rightarrow r>\frac {-2x+\sqrt{4x^2+12}}2=\sqrt{x^2+3}-x$$
$$\Rightarrow r^3+2(4x^3-3x)>(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x)^3+2(4x^3-3x)=:f(x),$$ hence to prove (2), it suffices to show that $$f(x)\geq 0~{\rm for~all~}x=\cos\theta,~{\rm namely~when~} |x|\leq 1.$$ In fact, one can show that $f(x)$ has only one real zero in $(-\infty,\infty)$ as in the following lemma.

**Lemma**. The function $$f(x)=(\sqrt{x^2+3}-x)^3+2(4x^3-3x)$$ has a unique zero at $x=\frac{\sqrt{6}}4$ in $(-\infty,\infty).$

*Proof*. Expanding, one has $$f(x)= (x^2+3)\sqrt{x^2+3}-3(x^2+3)x+3x^2\sqrt{x^2+3}-x^3+8x^3-6x$$
$$= (4x^2+3)\sqrt{x^2+3}+4x^3-15x=4x^2(\sqrt{x^2+3}+x)+3\sqrt{x^2+3}-15x>0~{\rm for~}x\leq 0,$$
hence $f(x)=0$ can only occur for $x>0.$ Now to solve the zeros, one has by the expansion above that $$f(x)=0\Leftrightarrow (4x^2+3)\sqrt{x^2+3}+4x^3-15x=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (4x^2+3)^2(x^2+3)=(4x^3-15x)^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 192x^4-144x^2+27=3(8x^2-3)^2=0$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2=\frac 3 8,$$ hence $$x=\frac{\sqrt{6}}4~{\rm if~}x>0.~~\Box$$

Since $f(x)$ is continuous, $f(x)>0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)>0,$ this shows that $f(x)>0$ except for $x$ at that zero. Thus the result of (2) (hence (1)) follows. $\Box$

**Remark**. Let $x=\frac{\sqrt{6}}4,r=\sqrt{x^2+3}-x=\frac{\sqrt{6}}2,y=\sqrt{1-x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{10}}4,$ and $z=r(x\pm iy).$ Then $|z+1|=2$ and $|z^3+1|=1.$

Answer (score 0):

$z\to |z^3+1|$ is a very smooth function.
It should suffice to analyze it on the circle $|z+1| = 2$.

That it grows faster outside of this circle is evident by the exponent of $z$.

Let $z = a+bi$

$(a+1)^2 + b^2 = 4$ is a rewritten equation for our our circle: $|z+1|^2 = 2^2$

Let us solve for $b^2$ with conjugate rule >

$b^2 = (2-(a+1))(2+(a+1)) = (1-a)(3+a)$

Now let us expand the second expression inside absolute values

$1+z^3 = 1 + a^3+i3a^2b-3ab^2-i*b^3$

$1+a^3 -3ab^2 + ib(3a^2-b^2)$

real part $1+a^3 -3ab^2$

imag part $b(3a^2-b^2)$

now we substitute using positive branch $b^2$, we will need to keep this symmetry in mind later.

$1 + a^3 -3a(1-a)(3+a))$

$\sqrt{(1-a)(3+a)}(3a^2-(1-a)(3+a))$

now square and sum and minimize over $a\in[-1,1]$

Since this is a polynomial in $a$ we can systematically find minima and maxima by regular methods in calculus.

Numerically we can find that $a = 0.75$ gives very close to $1$.

by setting it in we can verify that is where we achieve equality.

So if the question had been phrased $|z+1| \geq 2 \rightarrow |z^3+1| > 1 $

The answer would have been no, we have exceptions at the two points $a = 3/4, b = \pm \sqrt{2^2-(1+3/4)^2} = \pm \sqrt{15}/4$

Verifying, this should give precisely 2 and 1 respectively for the above absolute values.